# faithful representation of a Lie group acting on a smooth compact complex manifold with a fixed point.

Tags: complex-geometry

I will be please if someone can prove this to me.
Let X be a compact complex surface and G a compact Lie group acting on X with a fixed point p in X. Then G has a 2 dimensional faithful representation i.e., there exists a faithful homomorphism from G to Gl_2(C) or more precisely from G to T_pX (the tangent space of X at p which is isomorph to C^2).

Comment: $X$ is $2$-dimensional?

Comment: yes, sorry. It is a surface.

Comment: I don't get it - if your claim is true then for every such $G$ acting on $X$ one can define an action of $G\times S^1$ on $X$ by making the circle act trivially. Then the induced homomorphism $G\times S^1\to GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is not faithful any more!

Comment: It would help if you told us why you are trying to prove this statement (or whatever version of it that happens to be correct).  Maybe you want the isotropy group to be trivial in a sphere around $p$?


Comment: Yeah this is clearly false as stated.  It must be something like--$p$ is an isolated fixed point, $G$ acts holomorphically on $X$.

Comment: Thanks Somanth, I am not claiming my question is true.At Daniel: Your answers made me to change my question to G is acting holomorphically on the complex surface X. At Scott: I am thinking about the action of C_3 semidirectproduct C_7 on a compact complex surface and seeing why it doesnt fix a point?(if it fixes it will have a 2 dimensional faithful representation!!). Off course again you want to say this question is not related to complex geometry...!!!!! 

Comment: @ Rubik - What are the groups C_3 and C_7? And if this action of $G$ on $X$ has no fixed point then $X$ is a covering of $X/G$ and one can then possibly use Euler characteristic, i.e., $\chi(X)=\chi(X/G)\times |G|$. If it has fixed point(s) then there is a similar formula where one sums over the fixed point loci of the elements of $G$, assuming $G$ is finite. 

Comment: They are cyclic group of order 3 and  7, respectively. 